# Fourier transform of complex exponential with cubic power $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx e^{iax-ibx^3}$

Tags: improper-integrals, fourier-transform

How to evaluate the following integral, for real $a,b$?
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx e^{iax-ibx^3}
$$
If $b=0$, then the result is delta function $2\pi\delta(a)$ but how to do it for general b?

Comment: Why do you think there is a simplification? For $b=1$, WolframAlpha does not seem to have an answer https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fourier+transform+exp%28-i+x%5E3%29

Comment: @LL3.14 Mathematica also says that the integral is some sum of Bessel functions, or Airy functions. So I am not sure if I should trust it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me this question was screaming Airy function, so I looked up a few identities and found something pretty quick. From Abramowitz & Stegun (1965) we have
$$ A_i(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp \left[i\left(zx+\frac{x^3}{3}\right) \right]\,dx $$
or more generally, for all $\gamma \in \mathbb{R} \backslash\{0\}$,
$$ A_i(\gamma z) = \frac{1}{2\pi\gamma} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp \left[i\left(zx+\frac{x^3}{3\gamma^3}\right) \right]\,dx.$$
Letting $z=a$ and $\frac{1}{3\gamma^3}=-b \implies \gamma = -(3b)^{-\frac13}$, the desired integral is given by
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp \left[i\left(ax-bx^3\right) \right]\,dx = 2\pi\gamma A_i(\gamma z) = -2\pi(3b)^{-\frac13}A_i\left(-\frac{a}{(3b)^\frac{1}{3}}\right). $$

Comment: do we need to be careful about different roots of $(-3b)^{1/3}$?

Comment: Yeah sorry that identity is only for real $\gamma$ and $z$, so you must take the real root. You can imagine that if $\gamma$ is purely imaginary then that integral clearly wont exist as it will look like $\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{x^3}$.